# How can I compile a C++ project depending on Google's Filament Library on Windows using g++ (MSYS2/MinGW)?

Tags: c++, gcc, mingw, msys2

I'm a bit clueless about a problem I have encountered when trying to compile my C++ project, which uses [Google's Filament library](https://github.com/google/filament), with *g++* (MSYS2/MinGW) on Windows. It just vomits a giant load of error messages at me (see excerpts below). My guess is it is missing the MSVCRT, but I don't know for sure. If that is the case, shouldn't I be able to tell g++ that this library will be provided dynamically at runtime through the `msvcrt.dll` so it doesn't care about references for now?

`main.cpp`

```cpp
#include <filament/Engine.h>
#include <filament/SwapChain.h>
#include <filament/Renderer.h>
#include <filament/View.h>
#include <utils/EntityManager.h>

int main()
{}
```

Compile command:

```sh
g++ \
    -std=c++14 -pthread \
    main.cpp \
    -IE:/libraries/filament/1.8.1/include \
    -IE:/libraries/sdl/2.0.12/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include \
    -LE:/libraries/filament/1.8.1/lib/x86_64/mt \
    `E:/libraries/sdl/2.0.12/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/sdl2-config --libs` \
    -lfilament -lbackend -lbluegl -lbluevk -lfilabridge -lfilaflat -lutils -lgeometry -lsmol-v -libl \
    -lpthread
```

It spits out 1233 kilobytes of messages. Here are some excerpts:

At the beginning there are some *is-too-small-to-hold-all-values*-errors:

```
In file included from E:/libraries/filament/1.8.1/include/backend/Platform.h:22,
                 from E:/libraries/filament/1.8.1/include/filament/Engine.h:20,
                 from main.cpp:2:
E:/libraries/filament/1.8.1/include/backend/DriverEnums.h:631:30: warning: 'filament::backend::SamplerParams::<unnamed union>::<unnamed struct>::filterMag' is too small to hold all values of 'enum class filament::backend::SamplerMagFilter'
  631 |             SamplerMagFilter filterMag      : 1;    //!< magnification filter (NEAREST)
      |                              ^~~~~~~~~
E:/libraries/filament/1.8.1/include/backend/DriverEnums.h:632:30: warning: 'filament::backend::SamplerParams::<unnamed union>::<unnamed struct>::filterMin' is too small to hold all values of 'enum class filament::backend::SamplerMinFilter'
  632 |             SamplerMinFilter filterMin      : 3;    //!< minification filter  (NEAREST)
      |                              ^~~~~~~~~
(some more cut out)
```

Followed by like 40 lines telling me:

```
Warning: corrupt .drectve at end of def file
```

Then a lot of cryptic undefined references:

```
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: E:/libraries/filament/1.8.1/lib/x86_64/mt/bluegl.lib(bluegl.dir/Release/BlueGL.obj):(.text$x+0x8): undefined reference to `??1sentry@?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QEAA@XZ'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: E:/libraries/filament/1.8.1/lib/x86_64/mt/bluegl.lib(bluegl.dir/Release/BlueGL.obj):(.text$x+0x8): undefined reference to `??1_Sentry_base@?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QEAA@XZ'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: E:/libraries/filament/1.8.1/lib/x86_64/mt/bluegl.lib(bluegl.dir/Release/BlueGL.obj):(.text$x+0x8): undefined reference to `??1locale@std@@QEAA@XZ'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: E:/libraries/filament/1.8.1/lib/x86_64/mt/bluegl.lib(bluegl.dir/Release/BlueGL.obj):(.text$x+0x8): undefined reference to `??1_Lockit@std@@QEAA@XZ'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: E:/libraries/filament/1.8.1/lib/x86_64/mt/bluegl.lib(bluegl.dir/Release/BlueGL.obj):(.text$x+0x8): undefined reference to `??1?$unique_ptr@V_Facet_base@std@@U?$default_delete@V_Facet_base@std@@@2@@std@@QEAA@XZ'
(many many many more)
```

Some of them:

```
undefined reference to `__CxxFrameHandler4'
```

Which led me to my MSVCRT theory.

My g++ version:

```
$ g++ --version
g++.exe (Rev2, Built by MSYS2 project) 9.2.0
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Binary Filament for Windows ships with different lib versions: mt, md, mtd and mdd, explained [on the Microsoft website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/md-mt-ld-use-run-time-library?view=vs-2019). I thought the mt version would mean no static linking to MSVCRT and thus no reference problems during compilation. Maybe I am misunderstanding some things here?

Comment: I had a look at filament and tried to build it using MSYS2 and MinGW-w64, but it doesn't work out of the box. For starters the `CMakeLists.txt` are full of `if (WIN32)` where it should be `if (MSVC)`. Whoever wrote it just assumed Windows builds are always done with MSVC. So this project needs some work before it will build with MinGW.

Comment: Thank you for investiagting and sharing. But do you think it's necessary to build Filament itself with gcc? Shouldn't I be able to use the already compiled `.lib` files for static linking with gcc?

Comment: In my experience mixing libraries built with different compilers (or even different versions of the same compiler) often ends up in problems. This usually means different standard C/C++ libraries. For example memory allocated with `malloc()` in one library and released with `free()` in another may cause the application to crash if these functions don't come from the same standard library.
If you are very careful to avoid such issues you may get away with mixing compilers, but mistakes are easily made...